# Error while rosdep update

Tags: ros

I executed the following command in Ubuntu 16.04

> **rosdep update**

The error I am getting is as follows:

[image: error while rosdep update]

Internet is working fine and the links in error are also in working condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was happened due to the issues with proxy update.

Even though I change proxy to **NONE** as shown below

[image]

The proxy did not update properly on shell. If I type **echo "$http_proxy"** or echo **"$https_proxy"**, it was showing old proxy(which was down). So, it was the issue.

I restarted the system  after [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013547/where-to-change-proxy)

Now, rosdep updated properly.

[image]