# Where to change proxy

Tags: proxy

I generally use proxy for getting internet. Say proxy is xxx.xx.x.x.

But if the proxy is down, I select none and apply to system wide as shown below

[image]

After selecting none also, if I check for **echo "$http_proxy"** or **echo "$https_proxy"**. the output is my old proxy address **xxx.xx.x.x**.

I checked in **/etc/environment** and **.bashrc** for any proxy export statements but none are there. Why proxy is still active?

Where I have to change, so that the system won't consider proxy that I use generally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shell environment will be updated when you restart it.  If you are using a terminal window, just close it and open a new one.  Some times logging out and logging back in well fix these issues that persist.

Comment: Restarting solved the issue.

Comment: Glad that helped!